# Docker root directory issues

Tags: linux, docker

When I run a docker image of debian, the root folder seems be a bit out of place. For e.g : when the docker containers root folder seem to be at some place like this :

/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/f5656c3118921437130c22785982f09c2695e23ade334809091b6dc5918d6298

when I login into the docker container, all my root directory is at `/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/f5656c3118921437130c22785982f09c2695e23ade334809091b6dc5918d6298`

If I do a "cd /" then it goes to the hosts / directory , directly from the container. I have not done any mount, it just simple run of a debian image.

docker info :

```
docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.10.0
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 10
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 3.2.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 18
Total Memory: 35.43 GiB
Name: <hostname here>
ID: J6MI:XV6G:77NB:UNBK:GZC5:RZIA:DC2B:KZDZ:TEQQ:25KQ:AFSE:KACG
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

why is this happening. On my mac laptop if I run this image, it correctly mounts the root to / on the container. On a debian VM when I run this - it gives me the above behaviour. 
Is this expected? How do I change the behaviour ?

Comment: "I do a "cd /" then it goes to the hosts / directory" — How can you tell?  If you're running a Debian image on a Debian host, the `/` directories of the container and host would look the same at first glance.

Comment: e.g : from the container -  create a file "x" at /, and exit the container and go to host's / , you will see "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your kernel version 3.2 in your Debian host system is too old. Docker [requires a kernel version of at least 3.10](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/binaries/). There's also a respective [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=774376) in the Debian bugtracker.

For Debian Wheezy, you can install the Jessie kernel (should be 3.16-something) from the backports repository (see [this answer from the Unix&Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23695/how-to-update-debian-kernel-to-latest-in-backports) for more information).